# How do I pass a named function from an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have a simple

```
$(document).on('#happyButton', 'click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //more goes here... 
});
```

and I'd like to turn that into something akin to:

```
doStuff = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //more goes here...
}

$(document).on('#happyButton', 'click', doStuff(event));
```

As to be able to place this code in separate places, and more importantly run this elsewhere:

```
$(document).off('#happyButton', 'click', doStuff(event));
```

Unfortunately, this gives me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'preventDefault' of undefined
```

Now, the *right* answer is to "use backbone!" but this is a refactor of previous code and I don't have the weeks of luxury to refactor it all. I can also do a simple

```
$('#happyButton').off()
```

and I will as necessary, but I'd prefer the former as a cleaner solution.

Does anyone have other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You just need to pass a reference to the handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event is passed automagically:

```
$(document).on('click', '#happyButton', doStuff);

function doStuff(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
    //event is available
}
```

and it's:

```
.on(event, selector, handler)
```

not:

```
.on(selector, event, handler)
```

same with `off()`

Comment: Thanks! It also hit me square in the face on my way home that I wasn't passing a call to the function in (which would return the result) but the function itself.